# "Up Arrow" history in Python on OS X and code.InteractiveConsole

Tags: python, macos, readline, read-eval-print-loop

I use the following trick in some of my Python scripts to drop into an interactive Python REPL session:

```
import code; code.InteractiveConsole(locals=globals()).interact()
```

This usually works well on various RHEL machines at work, but on my laptop (OS X 10.11.4) it starts the REPL seemingly without readline support. You can see I get the `^[[A^C` garbage characters.

```
My-MBP:~ complex$ cat repl.py 
a = 'alpha'
import code; code.InteractiveConsole(locals=globals()).interact()
b = 'beta'
```

```
My-MBP:~ complex$ python repl.py 
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> a
'alpha'
>>> ^[[A^C
```

If I call `python` directly, up arrow command history in the REPL works fine.

I tried inspecting `globals()` to look for some clues, but in each case they appear to be the same. Any ideas on how I can fix this, or where to look?

Edit: And to show the correct behavior:

```
My-MBP:~ complex$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'a'
'a'
>>> 'a'
```

Answer (score 5):

Just `import readline`, either in the script or at the console.

Comment: Doing `import readline` does indeed give up arrow command history. That is helpful. However, why don't I have to import the deadline module when running "bare" `python`?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think it's an issue with your installation. I have the exact same behaviour on OSX 10.10 and when I ssh into an Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

The program `rlwrap` solves this problem in general, not just for Python but also for other programs in need of this feature such as `telnet`. You can install it with `brew install rlwrap` if you have Homebrew (which you should) and then use it by inserting it at the beginning of a command, i.e. `rlwrap python repl.py`.

Comment: Appreciate the pointer to rlwrap. However, I don't have Homebrew installed and don't plan on doing so (for reasons not relevant here). I'd to figure out how and why this doesn't work with the built-in `python`.